# cannot find place to associate stored access policy to SAS

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-account

i have created SAP (stored access policy) at container level. Gen2 storage

now when I am going to a particular file inside a container and right-clicking and then "generate SAS". I do not see any option to associate SAS to SAP.

I can see Microsoft articles where they say it is possible, but i do not see it on azure portal. no matter what i select on SAS tab (account key or user-delegation key). i still don't see where to select one particular SAP. [image]

I tried using storage explored, as mentioned in some of the help steps. somehow my storage explored right-click at container level has lot less options.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: I find the azure portal only offer the blob SAP. Others you can go to use Azure storage explorer.

Comment: And SAS, SAP is different thing. Stored access policies are not supported for the user delegation SAS or the account SAS

Comment: i found the issue. i need to have OWNER access to storage-account. once i changed it, i was able to see those additional options i was taking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS (shared access signature) with SAP provides additional layer of security. as SAS is hard to track once created.

steps to do will be

1. create SAP at container level, this can be done either via azure portal or via azure storage explorer.
2. 2nd step is to create SAS, this step has to be done via azure storage explorer (again, this step will not work on web).

--note: like me, if you do not see this option on storage explorer, this is to do with your role. you need to have **OWNER** role to storage account, to perform this step.

Answer (score 0):

On portal it seems only offer the blob SAP.

It is in this place:

[image]

Others need you to use REST API to send request.

Have a look of the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/define-stored-access-policy

> Stored access policies are not supported for the user delegation SAS
> or the account SAS..

SAP can define few things, and it and SAS are two different things, you can only choose one of these to use.

And you can set the SAP on Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Then do something like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: i think issue was much to do with right on the storage account. once i changed my role to "owner". I was able to see comprehensive list :) , as expected.